# Oracle development, SQL Primary key conundrum

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have an Oracle development requirement that appears to logically impossible to implement and I can use some help coming up with a solution/workaround.

In summary, I need to detect that an incoming column value (degree_code) has changed from an existing column value in a vendor table. But the existing degree_code value in the vendor table is a component of a DE FACTO PRIMARY KEY, so there is no way to join to it if the incoming degree_code is different.

Assumptions:
  The vendor STUDENT_INFO table cannot be modified.
  The incoming data has no way of providing an OCCURRENCE_NUMBER.

Relevant tables:

A. vendor STUDENT_INFO table:

```
  no formal primary key, but a UNIQUE ROW can be found with 2 different     
  column combinations:

  1. STUDENT_ID_NUMBER/OCCURRENCE_NUMBER:

     Example:  student1, occurence1: a bunch of degree-related data
               student1, occurence2: a bunch of different degree-related 
               data 

  2. In addition a UNIQUE ROW is ALSO defined by the following DE FACTO
     PRIMARY KEY:

     STUDENT_ID_NUMBER
     <<<DEGREE_CODE>>> (MA,BA, etc., anticipated or achieved)                                                                               
     DEGREE_YEAR (anticipated or achieved)                                                             
     COLLEGE_ID  (Harvard, Yale, etc.)   
     SCHOOL_CODE (School of Law, School of Business, etc.)
     MAJOR_CODE  (Business, Astronomy, etc)                                                                                   
     START_DATE  (date enrolled)                                                                       
     END_DATE    (date degree completed)
```

B. staging/work table

```
  formal primary key: STUDENT_ID_NUMBER/OCCURRENCE_NUMBER
  degree-related columns with changed data values that are to be updated to 
  the vendor STUDENT_INFO table
```

A daily feed of student degree-related data is received, validated, processed and loaded to an Oracle staging/work table
via PL/SQL.

The OCCURRENCE_NUMBER that is required in the work table is unavailable in the incoming data and has to be retrieved from the vendor STUDENT_INFO table using the DE FACTO PRIMARY KEY to identify a matching row.

When the loading of the staging table is completed, it is joined to the STUDENT_INFO table, matching on  STUDENT_ID_NUMBER/OCCURRENCE_NUMBER and changes from the staging table are then updated to the STUDENT_INFO table.

Other than tendering my resignation, can anyone suggest a solution to this?

TIA

Luke

Thanks to all who replied.

Scenario is: The fact that a change in degree_code for student_id_number '1' has occurred needs to be identified
and then revised from 'MA' to 'MBA' in the STUDENT_INFO table.

Here is sample data to help clarify:

vendor STUDENT_INFO table:

```
                      row 1           row 2
                      -------------   -------------
STUDENT_ID_NUMBER     1               1
OCCURRENCE            1               2
DEGREE_CODE           BA              MA
DEGREE_YEAR           2000            2000
COLLEGE_ID            AA              AA
SCHOOL_CODE           BB              BB
MAJOR_CODE            CC              CC
START_DATE            19990131        19990131
END_DATE              20010131        20010131


STAGE/WORK table:

                      row 1
                      -------------
STUDENT_ID_NUMBER     1                 incoming data
OCCURRENCE            2                 this needs to be retrieved from STUDENT_INFO table. STUDENT_ID_NUMBER/OCCURRENCE
                                          is the key used in the vendor proprietary update process to update the STUDENT_INFO table
DEGREE_CODE           MBA               incoming data
DEGREE_YEAR           2000              incoming data
COLLEGE_ID            AA                incoming data
SCHOOL_CODE           BB                incoming data
MAJOR_CODE            CC                incoming data
START_DATE            19990131          incoming data
END_DATE              20010131          incoming data
```

If more clarification is needed, I am happy to oblige...

Luke

Comment: Maybe try to add some sample input data and expected result. It's really hard to understand what you want.

Comment: This isn't a business requirement/user story, this is a technical decision that has been made in order to fulfill one. You're afflicted by the [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179419). Whilst your statement is objectively true, it's impossible to join on something that doesn't exist I suspect there's some additional information that makes this possible, i.e. there will only ever be a modification to the latest "occurrence" and ... You need to state the actual requirement and provide examples of the data both before and after in order to get a decent answer.

Comment: I'd also suggest that tendering your resignation might be considered a bit extreme... I'd favour talking with your colleagues first.

Comment: It is not helpful to use "de facto" when it has no understood meaning in this context. Either something is a PK or not, and either it is a candidate key or not. Take as many words with understood meanings and as much effort as you need to say what you mean. It is frequent that we don't find out what we mean until we have found how to say it.

Comment: With the info you provided, there is no way to tell that incoming data student 1, degree MBA, has to trigger an update to occurrence 2. For all I know, it might as well be a new occurrence 3. Does the rest of the data (student+college+school+major+start_date) qualify as a candidate key? Or can they be updated as well?

Comment: So what did you find out about your requirements?